# Make Enter key on an HTML form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a simple register form. What I want is, when I press Enter key it should submit my form. I tried several attempts but they didn't work.

**HTML code**

```
<p id="mtbox">Please Enter the Registered Email &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="email" name="agendaEmail" id='agendaEmail' onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);"/></p>
<button type="button" id='goSubmit'onclick="getMailList($('#agendaEmail').val())">Go</button>
```

**js code**

```
$("#agendaEmail").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#goSubmit").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not have any form, where it will submit?

Comment: @Butterfruit - AJAX maybe?

Comment: Wrap your above HTML in form element. that will handle enter key automatically.

Comment: I don't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/HJmx3/

Comment: @Butterfruit i have only one input field basically it is popup window :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a from and make an id for that and use the below code

```
$("#agendaEmail").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#goSubmit").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have put the keyup function inside the ready ? Didn't find any problem in your code other than this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#agendaEmail").keyup(function(event){
         if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#goSubmit").click();
                 }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery's `trigger` function to artificially press the submit button

Here is a fiddle with the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/uea68/

```
$("#agendaEmail").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#goSubmit").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Reference: jQuery Trigger - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: hi, thanks for replaying james but the problem is still there i tried your code but it is not working. the one main thing is, input field is in a popup boX.

Comment: Hello @user3239284 is it an external popup or a DIV popup? In both cases, the above code should work. Can we see how you are using it? Any links.

Answer (score -1):

Add a form first and insert the code that is necessary.

```
 <form> </form>
```

Comment: The `<form>` tag is not compulsory. The programmer can use Javascript to get the input field value and submit it via other means such as AJAX.